# How to select a whole line for as a motion in Vim?

Tags: vim, surround

I recently started to use the "surround" plugin. I realized I don't know how to surround the current line. I mean, `ysap<p>` surrounds a paragraph and `ysaw<p>` surrounds a word. Apparently `dw` deletes a word and `das` deletes a sentence. `dd` deletes a line, however, the second `d` is not a selection I'm afraid. So `ys??<p>` for a line?

Comment: Note: this question seems to be about `surround.vim` plugin.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `_` movement.

Ryan's answer is also right,
`dd` is a easier to type version of `d_` and a lot of commands have this optimization.

As it turns out, `surround.vim` has it too  (thank you Ryan!) and cheats a bit.

As you can see with `:h _` it does actually not refer the current line, but the first non-blank character on the `[count] -1` line downwards. This is the behaviour `dd` etc. uses. But isn't really what we want in your usecase, `ys_` will actually give you this:

```
"
line
"
```

Instead of this:

```
"line"
```

So the `surround.vim` plugin "cheats" a bit, by implementing a `yss` command which does not work like `dd`, `cc` or `yy` but works for the usecase it has.

So to answer the question as in the title: `_` is the general solution.

If you are just looking for `surround.vim` use Ryan's answer

Answer (score 32):

Repeat `s` (`yss`), like `cc`, `dd`, `yy`.